# Extract lines between two patterns from a file

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I need to extract particular lines between two matching patterns from a huge file.

Let's say `pattern1` (unique in a file) matches a particular `line # n` and `pattern2`  (not unique in a file) matches `line # m` next immediate match after `line # n`. Then I want to extract all lines between and including `line #n to #m`

**Sample File contents**

```
***************************************************************************
text line # n-2
text line # n-1
********************************* Results *********************************
SUCCEEDED
...
...
some text
***************************************************************************
text line # m+1
text line # m+2
***************************************************************************
```

**Desired Output**

```
********************************* Results *********************************
SUCCEEDED
...
...
some text
***************************************************************************
```

It would be appreciated if you could help me solve this problem

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate to the one I opened to cover all cases. This way, we have a main place with good explanations on this topic.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be an approach:

```
$ awk '/pattern1/ {p=1}; p; /pattern2/ {p=0}' file
********************************* Results *********************************
SUCCEEDED
...
...
some text
***************************************************************************
```

- When it finds `pattern1`, then makes variable p=1.
- it just prints lines when `p==1`. This is accomplished with the `p` condition. If it is true, it performs the default awk action, that is, `print $0`. Otherwise, it does not.
- When it finds `pattern2`, then makes variable p=0. As this condition is checked after `p` condition, it will print the line in which `pattern2` appears for the first time.

If you want an exact match of the lines:

```
$ awk '$0=="pattern1" {p=1}; p; $0=="pattern2" {p=0}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
***************************************************************************
text line # n-2
pattern1
********************************* Results *********************************
SUCCEEDED
...
...
some text
***************************************************************************
pattern2
text line # m+2
pattern2
***************************************************************************
$ awk '/pattern1/ {p=1}; p; /pattern2/ {p=0}' a
pattern1
********************************* Results *********************************
SUCCEEDED
...
...
some text
***************************************************************************
pattern2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but I can't match line # n-1 and line # m+1. They are not deterministic

Comment: @jkshah oh, now I see. Check my updated answer. I take into account the fact that you are looking for a pattern1, see the test.

Comment: updated ans excludes line #n and #m, which is not desired. Can you please check? It seems your solution in line with what is suggested by @Jotne and it works fine.

Comment: It does not exclude line #n and #m. This solution provides a more general approach for you looking for specific pattern1 and pattern2.

Comment: I substituted `Results` for `pattern1` and `^[*]+$` for `pattern2` and it removed starting and ending lines. Am I doing something worg? bdw +1 for your explanations

Comment: Ok, I was getting confused with the fact of printing `n` or `n+1`. Now I turned the condition so both lines are printed: the one with `pattern1` and the first with `pattern2`. Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: Now that's perfect and concise. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/start_pattern_here/,/end_pattern_here/!d' inputfile
```

and in OP's specific case:

```
$ sed '/[*]* Results [*]*/,/^[*]*$/!d' inputfile
********************************* Results *********************************
SUCCEEDED
...
...
some text
***************************************************************************
```

Assuming that the unique pattern was `*** Results ***` and the non-unique one was `********`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works pretty fine.

Comment: @devnull, do you believe this solution preferable to the awk soluton? If so, can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/Result/ {p=1;print;next}  /^\*\*\*\*\*/ && p {p=0;print} p' file
********************************* Results *********************************
SUCCEEDED
...
...
some text
***************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This works pretty fine.