# shell command to extract after a string1 and before string 2

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file which I want to extract after "String1" and before "String2" using unix shell commands such as grep, awk, sed. 
Part of a text file as follows(I need to get after "Specific" and before the second dashed line):

```
    ------------------
    Specific:
    line1
    line2
    ------------------
    line3
```

Comment: That was great, just a quick question: how can I extract After and Before. The code presented takes takes the line starting with the pattern

Comment: To make it more clear, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [Extract lines between two patterns from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177808/1983854):

```
$ awk '/------------------/ {p=0}; p; /Specific/ {p=1}'  file
line1
line2
```

Quoting my own explanation:

> - When it finds `pattern1`, then makes variable p=1.
> - it just prints lines when `p==1`. This is accomplished with the `p` condition. If it is true, it performs the default awk action, that is,
>     `print $0`. Otherwise, it does not.
> - When it finds `pattern2`, then makes variable p=0. As this condition is checked after `p` condition, it will print the line in which
>     `pattern2` appears for the first time.

So the difference is that `------------------` line is checked before printing, so that the flag can be stopped. And `Specific` line is checked after printing, so that the flag is turned on without printing this specific line.

It could also be done using `next` after setting `p=1` so `awk` jumps to the next line:

```
awk '/------------------/ {p=0} /Specific/ {p=1; next} p' file
```

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks a lot. Brilliant explanation - great help

Comment: @Ramin glad that it worked to you :) Also, you can accept the answer if your issue is solved.