# Extract lines between two patterns from a file, not including the end-pattern matches

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I want to do the same as in

[Extract lines between two patterns from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177721/extract-lines-between-two-patterns-from-a-file)

but I want to *not* have the line with the ending printed. Now, I could grep the results of the solutions to that question, I suppose - but can I, instead, make the `sed` or the `awk` solutions there use some kind of lookahead to not print the line matching the ending pattern?

Comment: For a moment I missed that this is a perfect duplicate! I recommend to at least try to google the headline of your intended question before clicking the submit button. ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl: I actually did do some googling, but that got me the related non-dupe...

Comment: No worries, I hope the answers in that thread are helpful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
sed -n '/begin/,/end/{/end/!p}'
```

That will print all lines in the range `begin` - `end` except of the line containing `end` itself from the output.

Comment: This will potentially also exclude the first line, if it matches `end` as well.

Comment: @andlrc: I wasn't thinking about that, but - if that's the case, then my question is rather poorly defined. So that's fine by me I guess.

Comment: I agree, if the line containing `begin` also contains `end`, then the range borders would have been poorly chosen.

Comment: @hek2mgl: just out of curiosity why does it don't give me the same out put when I use  sed -e '/begin/,/end/{/end/d}' ?

Comment: Because that would also print lines which are not part of the range

Comment: @hek2mgl : yes but why so , Why does it give the lines that are not part of the range ?

Comment: Because you are omitting `-n` .

Comment: PS: If you want to restrict yourself to the `d` command it would be `sed '1,/begin/{/begin/!d};/end/,/begin/{/begin/!d}'`

Comment: Actually I want to understand the difference between two commands 
sed -e  '1,/begin/{/begin/d}'  
and  sed -n  '1,/begin/{/begin/p}' 
sed -e  '1,/begin/{/begin/d}'   also brings the output  beyond the range (lines after begin also printed in output ) 
but  and  sed -n  '1,/begin/{/begin/p}'    brings the output with in the range (lines between 1 and begin)
How is the range being irrelevant with d ? shouldn't  sed -e  '1,/begin/{/begin/d}'  discard what's beyond the range specified ?

Comment: I've explained that to you. Probably you are missing the fact that sed will print all lines by default unless `-n` has been passed on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk one can control it easily:

```
$ awk '/begin/{p=1};/end/{p=0};p' input
```

Breakdown:

```
/begin/{p=1} # When current line matches `begin' then set p = 1
/end/{p=0}   # When current line matches `end' then set p = 0
p            # Print lines when p is truly, in this case when it's 1.
             # `p' starts empty, and will later be set to 0, which
             # are both falsy values.
             # It's only in the state p = 1 that the lines are printed.
```

You might by now notice how you can move `p` around to get a different result i.e, to print lines between `begin` and `end` but not the lines it self:

```
p; /begin/{p=1}; /end/{p=0}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity  can you explain how you command works it that a way to group commands in awk?

Comment: @user3369871 Updated with an explanation.

Comment: Your second example seems to print the second matching line.  Is there a way to exclude both lines?