# How to print data between certain tags?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a set of files (hundreds of them) with this kind of data (pipe as a column separator):

```
000|FILE___V20170307-003792
102|000|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|0001|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ADGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|GAFDGA|18||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASFAN||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|10|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
102|0100|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|00|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ASDGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|AGAH|5||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASDHAH||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|54|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
010|ENDOFFILE|10
```

How can I take only rows between the first row and the last row? First row has 000 in the first column and last row has 010 in the first column. I tried using awk:

```
awk '/000/,/010/ { print > "output.txt" }' input_file.txt
```

But it does not work and it does not check that 000 and 010 is found from the first column. Maybe somehow omitting the first and the last row works also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17988756/632407 ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22221277/632407 ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19177721/632407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^000|/,/^010|/{/^0[01]0|/!p;}' file

102|000|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|0001|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ADGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|GAFDGA|18||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASFAN||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|10|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
102|0100|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|00|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ASDGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|AGAH|5||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASDHAH||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|54|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
```

Using in a `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' -n '/^000|/,/^010|/{/^0[01]0|/!p;}' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I replace the content in the current files, I tried like `code` find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -n '/^000/,/^010/{/^0[01]0/!p;}' '{}' \;`code` but it just print the result?

Comment: You can use: `find . -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' -n '/^000|/,/^010|/{/^0[01]0|/!p;}' {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

you can try,

```
awk -v FS="|" '$1=="000",$1=="010" {print > "output.txt"}' input_file.txt
```

you get,

```
000|FILE___V20170307-003792
102|000|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|0001|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ADGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|GAFDGA|18||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASFAN||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|10|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
102|0100|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|00|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ASDGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|AGAH|5||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASDHAH||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|54|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
010|ENDOFFILE|10
```

also `only rows between the first row and the last row`

```
awk -v FS="|" '$1=="010"{f=0} f{print > "output.txt"} $1=="000"{f=1}' input_file.txt
```

you get,

```
102|000|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|0001|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ADGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|GAFDGA|18||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASFAN||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|10|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
102|0100|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|00|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ASDGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|AGAH|5||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASDHAH||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|54|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
```

Answer (score 1):

To get *rows between the first row and the last row* not considering the content at all, using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>2{print p} {p=$0}' file
102|000|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|0001|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ADGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|GAFDGA|18||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASFAN||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|10|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
102|0100|DDKSB=DAGA;DAGA=ADGA;DAG-FGSA=ADGA|00|KLJDFLKJBDL|00|ASDGAHA||00|ASYAHA|||DAGHAH|0|AGAH|5||3|N|1||AHA|ASGAN|ASDHAH||82|1||2|300|||0|0|0|0|54|0||0|0|KLJDFLKJBDL|2||||||||
```

Using `head` and `tail`:

```
$ head -n -1 file |tail -n +2
```

`man head`:

```
   -n, --lines=[-]K
          print the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the 
          leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file
```

`man tail`:

```
   -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to 
          output lines starting with the Kth
```

If you have several files, you can:

```
for f in files* ; do head -n -1 "$f" |tail -n +2 > newpath/"$f" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed -n '/^000/,/^010/{//d;p}' file
```

- `/^000/,/^010/`: from line starting with `000` to next line starting with `010`
- `//d`: deletes lines matching patterns in above address range
- `p`: output pattern space

Answer (score 0):

I would write more in a 'C-like' manner:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ ok = 0; FS = "|" } { if( $1 == "000" && ok == 0 ) { ok = 1; } if( ok == 1 ) { print; } if( $1 == "010" ) { ok = -1; } }' file
```